# How can I get ProductType information when executing a SetupActivity

Tags: moryx

I know that I can get `ProductType` or `ProductInstance` information from a `ProductionProcess` like this.

```cs
var instance = (ProductionProcess)activityStart.Process).ProductInstance;
var type = (ProductionProcess)activityStart.Process).ProductInstance.Type;
```

But what if I'm executing a SetupActivity created by a `SetupTrigger`.

```cs
public override void StartActivity(ActivityStart activityStart)
{
    _currentSession = activityStart;

    switch (activityStart.Activity)
    {
        case SomeSetupActivity setupActivity:
            var type = ?
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

How would I get the information which ProductType is expected to be produced here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Process.Recipe` points to the `ISetupRecipe` which has a `TargetRecipe` which points to the [ProductRecipe it is setting up for](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Factory/blob/dev/src/Moryx.ControlSystem/Recipes/ISetupRecipe.cs#L17). I would recommend to bind those values within the `Populate()` method onto parameters instead of reading them in the cell.

Comment: Could you elaborate how this binding would look like?